# unterminated string constant error. when converting an object to json string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, hyperlink

My json is like:

```
"ModelNo":"TEST 5","Weight":5,"ExportLevel":"Req'd","SafetyType":"UNDETERMINED"
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(rowObject);
```

I have tried the below code, but it didn't help:

```
jsonString.replace("'", "\\'");
```

I believe this single quote is the issue. Please help. How to escape this?

My Code:

```
me.getHyperlinkColumn = function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {       
    //var jsonString = JSON.parse(rowObject);        
    hyperLink = "<a href='#' id='hplinkactionUrl_" + options.rowId + "' onclick='" + options.colModel.CallMethod + "(" + options.rowId + "," + JSON.stringify(options) + "," + JSON.stringify(rowObject) + ")' style='text-decoration:underline; color:#3361b8;'>" + cellvalue + "</a>"
    return hyperLink;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us where `rowObject` is defined? `JSON.stringify({"ModelNo":"TEST 5","Weight":5,"ExportLevel":"Req'd","SafetyType":"UNDETERMINED"})` works without issue.

Comment: Please provide enough relevant code to reproduce this

Comment: rowObject is an object I get from jqgrid as a parameter.

Comment: I have updated with my code.

Comment: sure that isn't  a jQuery object? or dom node

Comment: Only in IE, this issue occurs. Script issue.

Comment: It is an array object. @charlietfl

Comment: why wouldn't you just use a jQuery click handler instead of  dumping that json in the DOM in an `onclick`?

Comment: because its a dynamic link, every property related to it is dynamic. I have tried every other way possible, this is the only way.

Comment: The JSON you have shown is not an array it's an object. It's also not valid JSON without curly braces surrounding it.

Comment: I know, i have have given part of the object. Yes its an object,

Comment: Is there any way to remove the apostrophe before JSON.stringify?

Comment: JSON.stringify does not escape characters for use in a URI. Have you tried `encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(rowObject))`?